# .htaccess to deny .php extension but unable to fire AJAX requests

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have added .htaccess tweak to deny all requests to .php files and internally redirect all non .php requests to .php files.

Everything is working fine on my LocalHost, but in production environment file upload script failed (I found that the file upload script use JS/Ajax call to a php file, which is not loading)

My .htaccess config is:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Return 404 if original request is /foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

and the JS call is :

```
<form class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm" action="ads_upload"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                        <div class="fallback">
                            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

...............

```
 $.post("ads_upldDelete?fname=" + file.name);//up-deletefile.php
```

Both ads_upload.php and ads_upldDelete.php is exisitng in the server, but can't reach because of the mode rewrite rule, Can i write and exception in mode rewrite to allow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Return 404 if original request is /foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ads_up(?:load|ldDelete)\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

And use `ads_upload.php` or `ads_upldDelete.php` with links.

Comment: What if 2 distinct names like ads_upload.php and ads_tryagain.php ? Can I write : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(ads_upload.php|ads_tryagain.php)$ [NC] ?

Comment: Yes, you can ! The same with more than 2 `(?:x|y|z|…)`